# How to set different background color to each ListView items in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

I've been gone through many tutorials and I'm only able to switch between two colors by checking whether the index is even or odd.

Here is my Code:

```
class PageTwoState extends State<PageTwo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemExtent: 250.0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.cyan : Colors.deepOrange,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(index.toString()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want each item to have a different background color(suppose if I have 10 items in my list then I want each item to have a different background color.), but by using a ternary operation I'm not able to do that.

Comment: How to want to get the color? Do you want it to be random or some kind of gradient? How do you expect to calculate a color from an index?

Comment: Ya some kind of gradient.

Comment: I want to calculate it through Index. Do I need to define some kind of array?

Comment: It really depends on your application. You could predefine an array if you know the number of elements beforehand or you can use a `ColorTween` to dynamically create a gradient with a list of variable length.

Comment: Okay I will read ColorTween, No I don't know the number of elements.

Comment: Assuming you know what colors the beginning and end of the `ListView` should be, this should be a good application of `ColorTween`.

Comment: If it would be not complicated, can you share a small snippet of code or else I will go through it.

Comment: Yeah I could. Could you provide me with an initial and ending color? Is this an infinite list?

Comment: AmberAccent to OrangeAccent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218225/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-praveen-gupta).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to generate random colors, then use this:

`import 'dart:math';`

`color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],`

If you have known number of items in the list, you can have a list of the colors you want:

```
class PageTwoState extends State<PageTwo> {

  //ADDED
  var colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.cyan,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.yellow,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemExtent: 250.0,
      itemCount: 5,//CHANGED
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Material(
          elevation: 4.0,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          color: colors[index],//CHANGED
          child: Center(
            child: Text(index.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Hardik Kumar, Actually I'm not sure about the number of elements in my list,sometimes it goes more than hundred and sometimes only 2-3 elements.

Comment: @PraveenGupta you can put modulus of the index to get color from Colors like this : colors[index % 5] that should solve your problem

Comment: I've edited my code to generate random colors. You can check it now

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example that uses `ColorTween` to create a gradient with consistent beginning and ending colors.

```dart
class PageTwoState extends State<PageTwo> {
  ColorTween color = ColorTween(begin: Colors.amberAccent, end: Colors.orangeAccent);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int listLen = 15; //Input the length of the list you retrieve from firebase here
    //The gradient will adjust for variations in length by itself as your database changes.
    
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listLen,
      itemExtent: 250.0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              color: color.lerp(index/(listLen-1)),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(index.toString()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

This will only work with a `ListView` with a finite length. But it seems you are retrieving a finite `List` of elements to show from firebase, so this should work out just fine for you. You just have to tell the builder how many elements the `List` you want to show has.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to generate random colors and save them in a list to check if they are already used by one of your element.
Here is a way of doing so:

```dart
List<Color> _alreadyUsedColors = [];

Color _randomColor() {
   Color newColor = Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
   while (_alreadyUsedColors.contains(newColor))
      newColor = Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
          .withOpacity(1.0);
   _alreadyUsedColors.add(newColor);
   return newColor;
}

// Then use it like this in your widget
Material(
   elevation: 4.0,
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
   color: _randomColor(),
   child: Center(child: Text(index.toString())),
)
```

You add to your `_alreadyUsedColors` each new color generated to ensure they are used only once and the `_randomColor` method will return the color to your `Material` widget.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have limited amount of  (for ex. 3) colours but an infinite number of list items. The following example demonstrates how to iterate 3 colours to whole list linearly.

```dart
void main() {
  final myList = [1, 2];

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print(myList[i % myList.length]);
  }
}
```

result

```
1
2
1
2
1
```

ListView will work same way

```dart
 final _colors = [
    Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.1),
    Colors.red.withOpacity(0.1),
    Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.1),
    Colors.green.withOpacity(0.1),
  ];

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              color: _colors[index % _colors.length]
              child: ListTile(),
            );
          },
        );
```